# Trouble viewing MaxEnt output map

Tags: java, maxent

I recently downloaded MaxEnt Model v3.3.3e software from http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/maxent/ website.  I have troubleshot many issues, and have success running the program with output files to view. However, the output file does not provide me with a picture of the map. I do get the html document with all the statistics and plots, and I also get a plots folder, but I do not get a picture or map showing the niche model of my species.

Would anyone know why this might be happening?  Would this have to do with what options I check before I run the program?  Any thoughts or suggestions would be most helpful. Thanks.

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Have you ticked the option 'Make pictures of predictions' in the main MaxEnt window? In case you didn't realise, MaxEnt will also create an .asc file (by default) which you can load into your GIS Software or R. This is probably the better way to go because you can then fully customise map colours and remove the black background ;)